# Ephesians 2:2, are there versions other than (DRB), (WYC) and (LV) having the word "this"?

Tags: word-study, ephesians

Ephesians 2:2, Latin Vulgate (LV):

> 2. in quibus aliquando ambulastis secundum saeculum mundi huius secundum principem potestatis aeris **huius** spiritus qui nunc operatur in filios diffidentiae

Ephesians 2:2, Douay-Rheims (DRB):

> Wherein in time past you walked according to the course of this world, according to the prince of the power of **this** air, of the spirit that now worketh on the children of unbelief:

Ephesians 2:2, Wycliffe Bible (WYC):

> 2 in which ye wandered sometime after the course of this world, after the prince of the power of **this** air, of the spirit that worketh now into the sons of unbelief;

I read about 60 English translations of the Bible, and Latin Vulgate. I didn't find the word "**this** air"except in Latin Vulgate and its English translation Douay-Rheims Bible and the related Wycliffe Bible.

Are there any other versions having the word "**this** air"?

Is this word "**this** air" present in any original Greek manuscripts?

I noticed that the word "virgin" in Genesis 34:2 is found in three versions only, i.e: LV, DRB and WYC.

How some words found in Latin Vulgate and not found in any original Greek, Hebrew manuscripts?!

Comment: Because like your other recent questions, "perfect translation" is not possible, and every word in a translation is not found in the original Hebrew or Greek.

Comment: @curiousdannii I just want to know is the word "this" mentioned in other versions of the Bible?, It is just a simple question. From my point of view, we can reach a high accuracy of the Bible. I wonder, how are some words found in Latin Vulgate and not found in any original Greek or Hebrew manuscripts?

Comment: Because they had to make choices as they translated it, and sometimes their choices were not ones other translators would agree with.

Answer (score 3):

The Greek text according to three predominant compilations is

> ἐν αἷς ποτε περιεπατήσατε κατὰ τὸν αἰῶνα τοῦ κόσμου τούτου, κατὰ τὸν
> ἄρχοντα τῆς ἐξουσίας τοῦ ἀέρος, τοῦ πνεύματος τοῦ νῦν ἐνεργοῦντος ἐν
> τοῖς υἱοῖς τῆς ἀπειθείας (Nestle-Aland 27th ed.)·
>
> ἐν αἷς ποτε περιεπατήσατε κατὰ τὸν αἰῶνα τοῦ κόσμου τούτου, κατὰ τὸν
> ἄρχοντα τῆς ἐξουσίας τοῦ ἀέρος, τοῦ πνεύματος τοῦ νῦν ἐνεργοῦντος ἐν
> τοῖς υἱοῖς τῆς ἀπειθείας (Scrivener Textus Receptus)·
>
> ἐν αἷς ποτε περιεπατήσατε κατὰ τὸν αἰῶνα τοῦ κόσμου τούτου, κατὰ τὸν
> ἄρχοντα τῆς ἐξουσίας τοῦ ἀέρος, τοῦ πνεύματος τοῦ νῦν ἐνεργοῦντος ἐν
> τοῖς υἱοῖς τῆς ἀπειθείας (1904 Patriarchal Text)·

Aside from punctuation, all are in agreement.  According to the Nestle-Aland apparatus, there are no variants in the available Greek manuscripts.

---

As you can see from the above, the word "this" (οὗτος) is only present modifying ὁ κόσμος (in the genitive case:  τοῦ κόσμου τούτου).  The rest of the text reads:

> ... κατὰ **τὸν**
> ἄρχοντα **τῆς** ἐξουσίας **τοῦ** ἀέρος, **τοῦ** πνεύματος **τοῦ** νῦν ἐνεργοῦντος ἐν
> **τοῖς** υἱοῖς τῆς ἀπειθείας
>
> ... *according to **the** the prince of **the** power of **the** air, **the** spirit, now energizing in **the** sons of disobedience* (*Orthodox New Testament* translation)

---

The Aramaic (Syriac) text apparently is consistent with the Greek, not the Latin.  According to the Lamsa translation, the Peshitta here reads:

> *... In which you previously walked according to the course of this world, and according to the will of the supreme ruler of the air, the spirit of which is active in the children of disobedience*